# Reading different data from a textfile delimited with semicolons in C

Tags: c, text, file, input

How do one read different records of data that are separated with semicolons into an array in C?

*from textfile:* **Text One; 12.25; Text Two; 5; Text Three; 1.253**

```
fopen ...
for(i = 0; i < nrRecords; i++) {
fscanf(myFile, " %[^;];", myRecords[i].firstText);  /* Ok first text*/
fscanf(myFile, "%lf", &myRecords[i].myDouble1);     /* But goes wrong with first double */
fscanf(myFile, " %[^;];", myRecords[i].secondText); 
fscanf(myFile, "%d", &myRecords[i].myInt1);     
fscanf(myFile, " %[^;];", myRecords[i].thirdText); 
fscanf(myFile, "%lf",&myRecords[i].myDouble2);    
}
fclose...
```

Comment: If you read each field as a string %[^;];, do you get the correct text (" 12.25" in the second field for example)?

Comment: No the problem is that I am reading it into a structarray with "fixed" types.

Comment: I tried it and it worked correctly. Can you show the definition of myRecord struct?

Comment: struct myRecord{
 char text1[20];
 double price;
 char text2[30];
 int nr;
 char text3[30];
 double price2;
};

Comment: How does it "go wrong"? Why aren't you checking fscanf's return value?

Answer (score 1):

The usual advice is to read whole lines and then parse it with sscanf or strtok, or whatever.  It's too easy to lose your place in the input file if you sscanf directly from the file.  (i.e. the first time something doesn't match, you need a way to skip past it, unless you want to just abort there.)

Comment: How is it easy to lose your place?  It's not hard to skip the rest of the line, which is all you're otherwise doing if you toss the current line on error: `void ignoreline(FILE* f) { char c; for (;;) switch (fgetc(f)) { case '\n': case EOF: return; default:; } `.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `fgets` to read a line from the file, `strtok` to break it on the semicolons, `strcpy` to copy strings, `strtod` to convert to double and `strtol` to convert to long (and then cast down to integer).

Or, read the line and use a state machine to walk each character and perform the correct operation.  For example, you're going to copy each character into firstText until you reach a semicolon, then use `strtod` to eat the double, skip over the semicolon, copy bytes to secondText, etc.

Or, use a single scanf format string to break the line down into all fields

```
fscanf(myFile, " %[^;];%lf;%[^;];%d;%[^;];%lf", 
    myRecords[i].firstText,
    &myRecords[i].myDouble1,
    myRecords[i].secondText,
    &myRecords[i].myInt1,
    myRecords[i].thirdText,
    &myRecords[i].myDouble2);
```

And, as mentioned by others, check the return value of `fscanf`.

I prefer reading a line at a time, to avoid having a single bad line screw up all of the conversions that follow.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/). And then typecast the result in int or float.